# Setting up Anaconda environmental variable, complications from Miniconda

Tags: python, environment-variables, anaconda, miniconda

I just deleted Python from my computer due to a lot of issues that were pointing to something going wrong with installation. I wanted to reinstall Python using the Anaconda project/software manager since it seems to have so much suitable for data science.

I started following instructions here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgjEUcccRwM (article version: https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-python-on-windows-anaconda-c63c7c3d1444 )

So I ran the anaconda setup installer. But afterwards, when I tried launching the anaconda prompt it would fail every time with the following error message: `
More is on this stack overflow post, which I followed instructions in order to resolve the problem: [Anaconda3 activate.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507131/anaconda3-activate-bat-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

The solution on that stackoverflow was to install the most recent miniconda package, which they directly linked. So now I have two directories, one for Anaconda3 and one for Miniconda3.

Now, back to the first video i linked... I ultimately need to use anaconda without just the anaconda prompt. opening anaconda prompt and looking for the location of anaconda as well as python gives me the following

```
 (base) C:\Users\biney>where python (cmd: where python)
  C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\python.exe (returns this)

 (base) C:\Users\biney>where conda
  C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat
  C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
```

so... It's pointing to my miniconda directory, not the anaconda3 directory. I assume that it should be pointing to my anaconda3 directory-- is there any way to change this?

Secondly, the command line instruction in order to set the anaconda path variable isn't working. I typed into windows command prompt:

```
C:\Users\biney>SETX PATH "%PATH%;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3"
```

> **WARNING**: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.
>
> **SUCCESS**: Specified value was saved.

I also typed in this same command, while switching to the directory location of Miniconda3. Neither of these have resulted in any changed when I type `conda` or `python` into my command prompt or git bash, so now I'm stuck.

What do I do about these two versions of Anaconda? Which one should be I be trying to add to the path variable? And how to I properly set up environmental variables so that  I can use Anaconda and Python?

Answer (score 0):

The Stack overflow I link I included, [Anaconda3 activate.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507131/anaconda3-activate-bat-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

So installing mini conda through the link provided on that page (64 bit version)  https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe makes it so that anaconda3 isn't being used. I wasn't able to launch an anaconda command prompt after installing a3, but I was after referring to that stack overflow post and installing Mini Conda. That launched me a miniconda command prompt.

From there, I added two destinations to my path variable: `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts` and `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\` and now the python command works. So does the conda command in git bash.

I guess my concern is... I ran a setup.exe for anaconda3 and stuff. I clearly don't need anaconda3, and the only way I could get it is from updating. What should I do to get rid of andaconda3 and leave miniconda?  (Intuitively I would just delete the anadconda folder, however, I've yet to verify a method to uninstall anaconda and keep miniconda. So I'm going to avoid doing so)